# Project PHP in Netbeans return 404.0 or 500.24

Tags: php, netbeans

I want to learn about PHP and I want to get start with Netbeans. I have installed basic component such as XAMPP and JDK.  When I run it, the error of 500.24 appear so I disable ASP.NET Impersonation then it return me with 404.0 error. What installment do I lack or configuration I need to set up to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you are amateur start with Laravel framework, and mamp.

Comment: Welcome Nick! It is indeed good to learn new things but I believe you are putting way too many technologies on the table if you're an amateur. If you would like to get started with a smoother learning curve, I suggest you to start easier: maybe learn the basics of one package at a time starting from installing Apache with PHP support, write your first scripts and then add MySQL. If you are ok with it you can skip XAMPP altogether, otherwise go ahead and try that. If PHP is your preferred lingo don't touch ASP or Java until you have reasons to do that.

Comment: I want to try learning about PHP. And this is the only basic step. The project I created is nothing but a simple basic generated from Netbeans. At first, I only have Apache but it return me with 404. When I done a few research, some people stated that I need to install XAMPP as well for PHP project to run on Netbeans which I did and it returns me with 500.24.